# Draw arbitrary lines in margins, R plot with several panels

Tags: r, r-grid

I have this code

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(1:5, 5:1)
```

Which makes this plot

[image]

I'd like to be able to add random lines all  over the plot (see red lines for example). They could be on the plot themselves, inner margins, or outer margins.

- The line coordinates should not be relative to one of the panels. They should be relative to the entire plot area. Ideally, drawn before or after the plots are drawn.
- It should be possible for the lines to cross from one plot to another, and from the inner to outer margins.

I do not want to use ggplot2. I have a feeling I need to use `grid`, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't difficult. Adding a new white panel (all over the plots), You can draw the segments you want by `xpd = TRUE`

Here is my example;

```
set.seed(111)
random_segments <- data.frame(x0 = runif(5, 0, 2), y0 = runif(5, 0, 2), 
                             x1 = runif(5, 0, 2), y1 = runif(5, 0, 1))

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(1:5, 5:1)
plot(11:20, 20:11)
par(new = T, mfrow = c(1, 1))
plot(1, type = "n", axes = F, ann = F)
with(random_segments, segments(x0, y0, x1, y1, xpd = TRUE))
```

[image]

[EDITED]

You can do it with making white panel with corrdinate you want and no margin (you needn't use `xpd = TRUE` because of no margin).

```
set.seed(111)
random_segments <- data.frame(x0 = runif(5, 0, 1), y0 = runif(5, 0, 1), 
                             x1 = runif(5, 0, 1), y1 = runif(5, 0, 1))

def_par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(1:5, 5:1)
plot(11:20, 20:11)
par(new = T, mfrow = c(1, 1), mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(1, type = "n", axes = F, ann = F, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", 
     xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
with(random_segments, segments(x0, y0, x1, y1))
points(c(0, 0, 1, 1), c(0, 1, 0, 1), col = "red")  # to check coordinate
par(def_par)  # recover
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to have the coordinate system for the segments start at (0,0) for the bottom left and finish with (1,1) at the top right, or something similar?

Comment: Thanks, works! In my case no need for the def_par because the device is pdf and I have a `dev.off()` immediately after drawing the lines. Additionally, I had to use `oma = c(0,0,0,0)` as well otherwise there was a tiny gap. Otherwise, works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution by cuttlefish!
The key is `xpd = TRUE` (Allows to plot outside plot area)
Since I have typed, here it is...

```
dev.off()
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
par(xpd=TRUE)
plot(1:5, 5:1)
lines(x=-1:2,y=-2:1,col="red")
lines(x=-1:1,y=-1:1,col="red")
lines(x= 1:3,y= 4:2,col="red")
lines(x= 4:7,y= 5:8,col="red")
lines(x= 2:4,y= 5:7,col="red")
# Control the length & slope of lines
plot(1:5, 5:1)
lines(x= -1:1,y=2:4,col="red")
lines(x=rep(1,3),y=0:2,col="red")
lines(x= 1:3,y=rep(6,3),col="red")
lines(x= 3:6,y= 2:5,col="red")
lines(x=c(4,4.2,4.4),y=4:6,col="red")
```

[image: redlines]

Comment: Added edits to the question to clarify some issues.